# Custom Open File Dialog C++

Tags: c++, winapi

We have created a class to customize the open file dialog in c++.

There is character array 'm_fileNameBuf' to hold the selected files names. Since the buffer is set to 5000, it can hold a maximum of 5000 characters.

Later on, large number of files are added and hence the total number of file characters exceeds and it leads to a problem. So we increased the number to 100K. But again, there was a case where the even large number of files are added and it is causing problem.

So the question here is how to avoid this problem? Instead of hard coding the array, is there anyway we can handle it according to the file size?

```
class DLLEXPORT CustomOpenFileDialog
{
   ......
   ......

   private:
    OPENFILENAME m_OpenFileName;
    static const long m_fileNameBufSize = 5000;
    TCHAR m_fileNameBuf[m_fileNameBufSize];
    ......
}

CustomOpenFileDialog::CustomOpenFileDialog()
{
    .....
    .....
    m_OpenFileName.lpstrFile = m_fileNameBuf;
    m_OpenFileName.nMaxFile = m_fileNameBufSize;
}

void CustomOpenFileDialog::SetFileName(TCHAR* name)
{
    _tcsncpy_s(m_fileNameBuf, m_fileNameBufSize, name, m_fileNameBufSize);
    .....
}
```

Comment: what about strings?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` sounds like a good option.

Comment: @joh See the description for `lpstrFile` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew). That's how the system provided dialog communicates with client code.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question, but can't you use IFileDialog instead? The result is a dynamically allocated array you get from IFileOpenDialog::GetResults https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog-getresults

Comment: @SimonMourier That's brilliant!  I never knew about that.

Comment: Why is the user selecting hundreds of individual files to begin with? Perhaps a better design would be to put all of the files into a single folder, and then use `SHBrowseForFolder()` or `IFileOpenDialog(FOS_PICKFOLDERS)` to let the user select just the folder, and then you can enumerate the files inside that folder after the dialog is closed.